# Initialization of vector of objects

Tags: c++, object, vector, heap-memory

Before I put my question let me mention in advance that I am aware that this topic has been discussed a lot, but yet again by looking to most of the answers I failed to figure out the proper way to achieve what I want (most probably because I missed sth from the anwers given).
So, say I want to create 20 times a vector of objects (say of size ten each) that should be of global scope (in the sense that this is done inside a class and i want these vectors of objects to be passed outside the class).
So, I am really not sure if the following is valid:

```
for ( int i =0; i<20; i++)
 vector<A> * vec_of_class = new vector<A>(10);
 /*where A is the class and I use new to have them in the heap,
 so that they won't be local */
```

Now, I know that this means that I should be extra carefull with handling them
and make sure that I preper delete them, but I am not sure if the operation I am doing is valid. In general I want to achieve to initialize 20 different vectors of object A that can be used in the global scope (the operation is happening inside a function of an other class), I know that it could be used
a vector of vectors of object A, but I would like to find out how to do correctly this kind of operation (initializing 20 different vectors of object A inside the body function of an other class and use them globally).
I hope ,my question was not to confusing and you could give me some help here.

Comment: Ok, that's what I thougt too, but how can I do the operation properly then?

Comment: Why don't you just `vector<vector<A>> vec_of_class(20, vector<A>(10));` ?

Comment: I suspect you want a class member like this: `std::vector<std::vector<A> > member {20, std::vector<A>(10)};`. Et voila, 20 vectors of 10 elements each.

Comment: Your question is too vague. It's pretty sure what you propose is not valid. But to obtain a valid answer, you should precise the context of your question

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answers, but as I mentioned I would like to find a way to do this witout using a vector of vector.

Comment: @user3665594 Well in that case you need to create 20 different vectors like `vector<A> * vec_of_class1;`, `vector<A> * vec_of_class2;` etc which is bad. You can't create 20 different vectors with the same name.

Comment: What's wrong with vector of vectors? Why do you want to reject the most natural and straightforward solution to your stated problem? Is there something you neglect to tell us?

Comment: Do you actually want to "use them globally", or do you just need to return them from the class by-copy (probably with RVO) and use them outside of it thereafter?

Comment: The reason why I am asking for a solution with vector and not vector of vectors is because of other (unrelated with the question) reasons. That's why I try to udnerstand how it would be possible to initialize them via ten singe vectors instead of a vector of vectors

Comment: You'd need to explain those reasons. Until then, what we have before us is clearly an instance of an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/). If those reasons are indeed unrelated to the question as you claim, then how come they affect the solution thereto?

Comment: I want to be able to use the vector outside the class scope and to pass it to an other class, that's what i mean by saying globally.

Comment: @user3665594  Honestly, I don't understand your reasons for not choosing a vector when you're already using vector.  Why are you willing to use a `vector<A>` and not a `vector<T>`, where `T` just happens to be a `std::vector`?  Is it the name "std::vector" that is causing you concern?  A vector whose type *just happens to be vector* works no differently than a vector of any other type.

Answer (score 4):

There should never be a case when you dynamically allocate any standard container, including vector. So `std::vector<> = new <>` is always wrong.

To initialize your vector, you can use multitude of techniques. I find initializer lists especially handy, like here:

```
std::vector<int> vec{10, 20, 30, 40, 50};
```

Comment: Isn't it vector<int> vec = {10,20,30,40,50}; ?

Comment: @OmidCompSCI Both are valid

Comment: @underscore_d, thanks just glanced over uniform initialisation. I swear C++ is just way to big of a language god dam!

Answer (score 1):

> So, say I want to create 20 times a vector of objects (say of size ten each)

That's easy. Use:

```
std::vector<std::vector<A>> my_data{20, std::vector<A>{10}};
```

> that should be of global scope (in the sense that this is done inside a class and i want these vectors of objects to be passed outside the class).

I don't have a clear picture of what you want to accomplish here.

When something is done inside a class, it could be done in a `static` member function or a regular member function. It seems like you should use a `static` member function but I am not sure.

If you use a `static` member function, I would suggest:

```
std::vector<std::vector<A>> const& TheClass::get_my_data()
{
   static std::vector<std::vector<A>> my_data{20, std::vector<A>{10}};
   static bool inited = false;
   if ( !inited )
   {
      // Set the values of the elements in my_data
      // ...

      inited = true;
   }
   return my_data;
}
```

If you use a regular member function, I suggest populating `my_data` in the constructor and returning from a  function.

```
// Need to make my_data a member variable
TheClass::TheClass() : my_data{20, std::vector<A>{10}}
{
   // Set the values of the elements in my_data
   // ...
}

std::vector<std::vector<A>> const& TheClass::get_my_data() const
{
   return my_data;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you declare a variable into a function, the scope of that variable will be the function. It won't be accessible from outside.

What you can do is declare the 20 pointers in the global scope, and initialize them wherever you want (inside a function, for instance).